# 3 Monitors and Mouse Flicklering

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mouse, intel

I have done a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 64bit install, I have three monitors, two of them are conected to an Nvidia PCI-e card, the other is conected to motherboard's Intel video card.

The problem is that the monitor connected to the Intel is not detected correctly (it's an AOC monitor), so it appears as unknown, after playing with xrandr I managed to have it display at the correct 1366x768 native resolution.

The flickering of the mouse (in the monitors controlled by the Nvidia card) is caused by this "Unknown Monitor" issue, how can I fix it?

On the Nvidia I have another AOC monitor and a Viewsonic, both of them are detected correctly, but the mouse flickers or dissapears.